# how do i find the value in this al register?

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

i am working on a binary bomb lab assignment that deals with x86 assembly language (at&t i believe). i was running through my code and get to the end but at the end i am comparing a value of mine which is 306 to this %al register i do not know how to get the value of this as i have tries x and x/d for al and $al and it can not find it, how do i find the value of this.  This is in line 327. Thank you.

```
1 2 120

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048da4 in phase_5 ()

Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.8.i686

(gdb) disas

Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:

=> 0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp

   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)

   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax

   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)

   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)

   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)

   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)

   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>

   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax

   0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>

   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)

   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>

   0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)

   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax

   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)

---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q

Quit

(gdb) until *0x08048dd6

0x08048dd6 in phase_5 ()

(gdb) disas

Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:

   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp

   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)

   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax

   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)

   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)

   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)

   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)

   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>

   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax

=> 0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>

   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)

   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>

   0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)

   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax

   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)

---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q

Quit

(gdb) ni

0x08048ddd in phase_5 ()

(gdb) disas

Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:

   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp

   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)

   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax

   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)

   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)

   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)

   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)

   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>

   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax

   0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>

   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

=> 0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)

   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>

   0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)

   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax

   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)

---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q

Quit

(gdb) ni

0x08048de2 in phase_5 ()

(gdb) ni

0x08048de8 in phase_5 ()

(gdb) disas

Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:

   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp

   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)

   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax

   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)

   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)

   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)

   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)

   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>

   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax

   0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>

   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)

   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>

=> 0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)

   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax

   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)

---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q

Quit

(gdb) ni

0x08048dec in phase_5 ()

(gdb) ni

0x08048e15 in phase_5 ()

(gdb) disas

Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:

   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp

   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)

   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax

   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)

   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)

   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)

   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)

   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>

   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax

   0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>

   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)

   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>

   0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)

   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

=> 0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax

   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)

---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q

Quit

(gdb) ni

0x08048e1a in phase_5 ()

(gdb) x/d $esp+0x2c

0xffffce9c: 120

(gdb) ni

0x08048e1f in phase_5 ()

(gdb) ni

0x08048eeb in phase_5 ()

(gdb) disas

Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:

   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp

   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)

   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax

   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)

   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)

   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)

   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)

   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>

   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax

   0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>

   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)

   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>

   0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax

   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)

   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax

   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax

   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)

---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---

   0x08048e1f <+123>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e25 <+129>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048e2a <+134>:   mov    $0x73,%eax

   0x08048e2f <+139>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e34 <+144>:   mov    $0x64,%eax

   0x08048e39 <+149>:   cmpl   $0x1fd,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048e41 <+157>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e47 <+163>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048e4c <+168>:   mov    $0x64,%eax

   0x08048e51 <+173>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e56 <+178>:   mov    $0x66,%eax

   0x08048e5b <+183>:   cmpl   $0x363,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048e63 <+191>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e69 <+197>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048e6e <+202>:   mov    $0x66,%eax

   0x08048e73 <+207>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e75 <+209>:   mov    $0x70,%eax

   0x08048e7a <+214>:   cmpl   $0x161,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048e82 <+222>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e84 <+224>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048e89 <+229>:   mov    $0x70,%eax

   0x08048e8e <+234>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e90 <+236>:   mov    $0x6f,%eax

   0x08048e95 <+241>:   cmpl   $0x329,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048e9d <+249>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048e9f <+251>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048ea4 <+256>:   mov    $0x6f,%eax

---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---

   0x08048ea9 <+261>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048eab <+263>:   mov    $0x64,%eax

   0x08048eb0 <+268>:   cmpl   $0x273,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048eb8 <+276>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048eba <+278>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048ebf <+283>:   mov    $0x64,%eax

   0x08048ec4 <+288>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048ec6 <+290>:   mov    $0x62,%eax

   0x08048ecb <+295>:   cmpl   $0x2b8,0x2c(%esp)

   0x08048ed3 <+303>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048ed5 <+305>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048eda <+310>:   mov    $0x62,%eax

   0x08048edf <+315>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>

   0x08048ee1 <+317>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048ee6 <+322>:   mov    $0x67,%eax

=> 0x08048eeb <+327>:   cmp    0x27(%esp),%al

   0x08048eef <+331>:   je     0x8048ef6 <phase_5+338>

   0x08048ef1 <+333>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048ef6 <+338>:   add    $0x3c,%esp

   0x08048ef9 <+341>:   ret    

End of assembler dump.

(gdb) x/d $esp+0x27

0xffffce97: 306
```

Comment: Well, I can save you some trouble... There's no way that `al` can hold 306.

Comment: To help clarify: `cmp 0x27(%esp),%al` is a 8-bit comparison, so it's doing an byte-size load from memory `0x27(%esp)`. `x/d` uses whatever size was previously used, probably dword. To get a byte, add `b` to the format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

`print $al` (or `p $al`) will work. `x` doesn't work because it doesn't show the value, it shows the contents *at* that address (and `$al` isn't a valid pointer). You can also show all the registers at once, see [`info gdb Registers`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html).

> `info registers`
>
> > Print the names and values of all registers except floating-point and vector registers (in the selected stack frame).
>
> `info all-registers`
>
> > Print the names and values of all registers, including floating-point and vector registers (in the selected stack frame).
>
> `info registers` *regname* …
>
> > Print the *relativized* value of each specified register *regname*. As discussed in detail below, register values are normally relative to the selected stack frame. The *regname* may be any register name valid on the machine you are using, with or without the initial ‘`$`’.

Answer (score 0):

just use the below command

```
i r al
```

it will show the value in the %al register.